# Converting wrapped anchor tag HTML to link_to

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm messing around with Bootstrap.  There's some HTML code which is wrapped by an anchor tag.  I'm not really sure how to convert it to the Rails `link_to` method.  I looked at the Ruby on Rails documentation for `link_to` but I still cannot figure it out.

Here's the code:

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
```

I tried the following but it's incorrect:

```
<% link_to("Users", users_path, { data: { toggle: "dropdown" }, class: "dropdown-toggle"} ) do %>
  <b class="caret"></b>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the href is a pure '#" but no variables at all, it's better to copy the code directly from Bootstrap than making a `link_to`.

If you want to add variable/method say `user_path`, with this complex anchor, it's better to use the block argument of `link_to`. Move the first argument which is usually the anchor to the block.

```
<%= link_to users_path, data: {toggle: "dropdown"}, class: "dropdown-toggle" do %>
  <b class="caret"></b>
<% end %>
```